# Remove all users with a 0 at the end of profile name

Tags: batch-file, replace, cmd, find

I am trying to list all profiles on a machine. However, I want to ignore all profiles that end with 0.

What I have that will list all users is:

```
@ECHO OFF
:begin
SET "Value="
SET Users="dir \\my-pc\C$\Users\ /B /L"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%A IN ('%Users%') DO (
    SET "Name=%%A"
        IF /I "!NAME!" NEQ "Administrator" (
      IF /I "!NAME!" NEQ "ADMINI~1" (
           IF /I "!NAME!" NEQ !USERNAME! (
                SET "Value=!Value! "
                SET "Value=!Value!%%A"
            )
          )
        )
      )
echo %Value%
```

Result is:

```
  userA0 userB userC0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Desired result:

```
 userB
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Pipe the output of the `DIR` command to the `FINDSTR` command.

Comment: Thanks!    | FINDSTR /e [a-z]

Comment: I'd use `findstr /V /E "0"`. But note that the user profile folder name might not equal the user name, particularly when the user name has changed...

Answer (score 1):

If the computer you're retrieving the information from is elsewhere on the network you could try:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "UserList="
For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (`WMIC /Node:'My-PC'`  /User:'Administrator' /Password:'MyPa55w0rd' Path^
 Win32_UserProfile Where "Special='False' And Not LocalPath Like '%%0'" Get LocalPath 2^>Nul`
) Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%B In ("%%~nxA") Do Call :Sub %%~B
Set UserList 2>Nul
Pause
Exit/B

:Sub
If Not Defined UserList (Set "UserList="%*"") Else Set "UserList=%UserList%,"%*""
GoTo :EOF
```

If you're retrieving from the local PC perhaps:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "UserList="
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC Path^
 Win32_UserProfile Where "Special='False' And Not LocalPath='%UserProfile:\=\\%' And Not LocalPath Like '%%0'" Get LocalPath 2^>Nul'
) Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%B In ("%%~nxA") Do Call :Sub %%~B
Set UserList 2>Nul
Pause
Exit/B

:Sub
If Not Defined UserList (Set "UserList="%*"") Else Set "UserList=%UserList%,"%*""
GoTo :EOF
```

These are absolutely untested, as I have no access to a Windows PC, *just an Android phone*. If there are issues with them, please leave a comment and I'll try to modify as necessary when I get a chance.

Please note there are more robust methods than assuming a `%UserName%` will match the name of the profile directory. If you change a profile name, the directory holding their files does not change name to match the new name.

Answer (score 0):

```
dir c:\users\*0.* /ad | Findstr /c:Administrators /v
```

Wildcards are RegEx.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to fully explain your answer. As is, your post is unclear and could warrant deletion.